# Writing file when switching buffer

Tags: prelude, auto-save

I'm using a rather stock Prelude emacs version with `super-save` disabled, but still whenever I change buffers using `C-x o`, whatever buffer I currently have focused writes to disk. I still want the auto-save to happen, but not the full write that triggers a bunch of rsync stuff.

Where do I find the command that writes the file to disk so I can throw a debugger in there to find the stacktrace?

Comment: Have a look at `buffer-list-update-hook`. (That's one possible place.)

Comment: `M-x debug-on-entry basic-save-buffer`, to see what function chain calls for the saving. But first put `(cancel-debug-on-entry)` in a buffer such as `*scratch*` and be ready to use `C-x C-e` after it, to quickly cancel such debugging once you get your answer.